# Discord.py - Tag a random user

Tags: discord, discord.py

I recently started working with Discord.py. 
My question is: How can I tag a random user, for example if you write !tag in the chat? I haven't found an answer yet.

```python
 if message.content.startswith('+best'):
        userid = '<@ # A RANDOM ID #>'
        yield from client.send_message(message.channel, ' : %s is the best ' % userid)
```

Thank´s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. Generate a list of users in your server
2. Use `random.choice` to select a random user from the list
3. Mention that user using the API (or if you'd like, do it manually) along with your message

Here's the implementation:

```py
from random import choice

if message.content.startswith('+best'):
    user = choice(message.channel.guild.members)
    yield from client.send_message(message.channel, ' : %s is the best ' % user.mention)
```

Comment: You're mixing some syntax from the async and rewrite branches here.  On version 0.16, `guild` should be `server`, and on 1.0.0, `client.send_message(message.channel, ...` should be `message.channel.send(...`

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Development\Projects\mymanager.py\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Development/Projects/mymanager.py/main.py", line 62, in on_message
    user = choice(message.channel.server.members)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\random.py", line 265, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on aeshthetic's answer, you can do something like this:

```
import random

if message.content.startswith('+best'):
    channel = message.channel
    randomMember = random.choice(channel.guild.members)
    await channel.send(f'{randomMember.mention} is the best')
```

Please note that the code is in the rewrite version of discord.py and not the async version - if you're using the async version, I'd recommend you migrate to rewrite as support for the async version of discord.py has ceased. To learn more about that, refer to the migrating documentation found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).

Let me know if you need help - happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you install [`discord.py-rewrite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), as it is more advanced.

Then, I suggest you create bot commands using the `@client.command()` decorator, like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def testcommand(ctx):
    pass
```

Now that you have done both things, there are several ways to do it. For example, if you don't want the bot to mention the command invoker or other bots, you can write:

```py
from random import choice
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def tag(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.send(choice(tuple(member.mention for member in ctx.guild.members if not member.bot and member!=ctx.author)))
    except IndexError:
        await ctx.send("You are the only human member on it!")
```

If you don't want the bot to mention other bots, but it can mention the command invoker, use:

```py
from random import choice
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def tag(ctx):
    await ctx.send(choice(tuple(member.mention for member in ctx.guild.members if not member.bot)))
```

If you want the bot to mention any guild member, human or bot, use:

```py
from random import choice
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def tag(ctx):
    await ctx.send(choice(tuple(member.mention for member in ctx.guild.members)))
```

Comment: `"Then, I suggest you create bot commands using the @client.command()"`.

  What is the difference between `if message.content == "command"` and `@client.command()`?

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around a bit and got this to work, you can try it.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def hug(ctx):
    user = choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention} hugged {user.mention}')
```

Comment: This only mentions my bot? Does it mention offline users?